# Grep within folders with a space in their names

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, command-line-interface

I am trying to grep for a particular string within all folders within a root directory with the .cs extension. However, some of the folders have a space and so my grep command is failing.

Searched through other posts but couldnt find an exact answer. Is there a more efficient way to do this search ?

**Wondering what I could do to escape through this space within the folder or file name.**

```
find . -name \*.cs -print | xargs grep -win "Test String" > TesString.log
```

Folder with the space within my root -

```
D:\TestDrive\C Sharp\Batch\MyCode
```

Failure in grep

```
grep: ./TestDrive/C: Is a directory
grep: Sharp/Batch/MyCode/Program.cs: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive `grep` instead of `find | xargs grep ..`:

```
grep -winr 'Test String' --include=*.cs .
```

For your command, you need to use `-print0` and `xargs -0` to make `find` output nul terminated filenames:

```
find . -name '*.cs' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -win "Test String" > TesString.log
```

Alternatively you can use `-exec` option in `find` itself:

```
find . -name '*.cs' -exec grep -win "Test String" {} + > TesString.log
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava but this is not able to search for any file names with .cs extension though.

Comment: This shows all the files but when I run it with the grep command, it doesnt find the file - there is no output

Comment: Yes, I have a file with 'Test String' in it. I checked the output file too but nothing gets written to it either.

Comment: It works fine for me. Try: `grep -winr 'Test String' --include=*.cs .`

Comment: this latest one seems to work but it wont print the line number of the occurrence.

Comment: Never mind - I was not looking carefully. it does print the line number. is this the most efficient way to search through thousands of files though ?

Comment: Yes why not. It searches one file at a time so won't spawn multiple processes or threads.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Anubhava. Appreciate it.